# Prove that the ideal $(X+Y+1)$ is prime in $F[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $F$ be a field. Prove that the ideal $I=(X+Y+1)$ is a prime ideal in the polynomial ring $F[X,Y]$.

Comment: First idea : What does the quotient $F[X,Y]/(X+Y+1)$ look like?

Comment: Do you remember a result relating primality of an ideal $I$ in a commutative ring $R$ with a property of the quotient ring $R/I$? Can you somehow identify this quotient ring with another ring here (preferrably one that you are more familiar with)?

Comment: May I say that, if $\bar{f}\bar{g}=\bar{0}$ in $F[X,Y]/(X+Y+1)$, that is, $fg$ is divisible by $X+Y+1$, which is irreducible, so is prime in an UFD, we get $X+Y+1$ divides $f$ or $g$, so $\bar{f}$ or $\bar{g}$ is equal to $\bar{0}$, and therefore $F[X,Y]/(X+Y+1)$ is an integral domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the map $\phi:F[X,Y]\to F[X]:f(X,Y)\mapsto f(X,-X-1)$. What is its kernel?

Comment: I want to prove, given a ring homomorphism $\phi: (F[X])[Y]\rightarrow F[X]$ by $f(X,Y)\mapsto f(X,-X-1)$, it has the kernel $\ker{\phi}=(X+Y+1)$. The RHS includes the LHS is due to the division algorithm of (F[X])[Y], and the reverse inclusion is obvious. And the kernel of a ring homomorphism is a prime ideal of the ring of the domain. Do I understand your hint right?

Comment: Not quite: Generally $(F[X])[Y]$ will not have a division algorithm. Luckily, $F(X)[Y]$ (the polynomial ring over the function field $F(X)$) always has a division algorithm, so the conclusion still stands that $ker\phi =(X+Y+1)$. Secondly, the kernel of a ring homomorphism need not be a prime ideal (in general only an ideal). But: by the isomorphism theorem, $F[X,Y]/I$ is isomorphic to $im\phi$ which is a subring of $F[X]$ and hence an integral domain (in fact you can easily show $im\phi=F[X]$). We know that $F[X,Y]/I$ is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal, so we are done.

Comment: I know the part about the kernel but I write too roughly. Thanks a lot for the detailed explaination :)

Answer (score 0):

First observe that $X+Y+1$ is irreducible in $F[X,Y].$
Let $A(X,Y)B(X,Y)\in(X+Y+1)$ and we need to show that at least one of these two variable polynomials over $F$ is in $(X+Y+1).$  Note that the product $A(X,Y)B(X,Y)$ can be factored in to finite number of monic irreducible polynomials in a unique way such that $fP_1^{r_1}P_2^{r_2}\cdots P_N^{r_N}$ where $f\in F$ and $r_1, r_2, r_N\in\Bbb{N}.$ Also by the uniqueness of the factorization $X+Y+1$ must be one of these factors and that factor has to be came from either $A(X,Y)$ or $B(X,Y)$ or from both. This proves that $A(X,Y)\in(X+Y+1)$ or $B(X,Y)\in(X+Y+1).$